# Sharepoint 2013 Search File Share result source exclusion

Tags: query

I'm using the query builder to try and get the results excluded containing the string "archive" The content source is a file share, not a web page.

This is one of the hundred query transform variations that I tried:

```
ContentSource:file-server AND source=NewWork AND NOT source=archive
```

I also tried the managed properties source, path, url, folder even creating my own but I can't get an exclusion working. Any ideas?